# Using lambdas in a function within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment where I'm asked to modify some code. The original function is this:

```
def selectivelyCopy(inputFile,outputFile,predicate):
  linesCopied = 0
  for line in inputFile:
    if predicate(line):#test the line with the predicate
        outputFile.write(line)
        linesCopied+=1
inputFile.close()
return linesCopied
```

Now I am suppose to add the parameter *transform*, a function that takes in as its parameter a string, and returns a string according to the transformation specified by the user. If *transform* is omitted from the function call, lines from the input file are written unchanged.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def selectivelyCopy2(inputFile,outputFile,predicate, transform):
    def transform(x = lambda x: x):
        return(x) 

    linesCopied = 0
    for line in inputFile:
        if predicate(line): #test the line with the predicate
            outputFile.write(line)
            linesCopied+=1
    inputFile.close()
    return linesCopied
```

I'm not sure where to proceed from here. I think I'm suppose to read the input file line, but write the transformed line...or something?

Comment: Try running the code. You're CPU's time is worth less than ours. Also tag as homework if this is homework.

Comment: I did run it. It just runs as if the definition wasn't there. No errors.

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious, but ... you run the code above? With nothing extra? Did you _call_ your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Now I am suppose to add the parameter transform, a function that takes in as its parameter a string, and returns a string according to the transformation specified by the user. If transform is omitted from the function call, lines from the input file are written unchanged.*

That sounds to me very simple: you are supposed to accept a function argument called `transform`, and if it is supplied, you call it.  If it is not supplied, you either don't call it, or else you call a trivial function that returns its input unchanged.

I suggest that you use a default argument of `None` for `transform`.  Then check to see if `transform is None`.  If it is not, then try to call it, passing the current line, and collecting the output as the new current line.  If `transform is None` then you just write the current line unchanged.

Alternatively, you could declare this trivial function:

```
def nop(x):
    return x
```

And then specify that the default for argument `transform` is the function `nop`.  Which is better, to test for `None` and call nothing, or to have a sensible no-operation default function and always call it?  I think this is mostly a matter of personal preference.  The test for `None` avoids the overhead of a function call, so it is probably slightly faster, but it probably isn't a big deal either way.

There is no reason to declare a private function named `transform`, and by doing that you are making it impossible to check what the argument `transform` is.

Comment: You took the words right out of my mouth.  Slightly more elegant, but also less inefficient, might be to set transform's default to `transform = lambda x: x` so that you can you can always call transform instead of checking whether it is `None`.  You definitely hinted at the idea, just thought I'd mention it more explicitly.

Comment: I usually tend to make named functions like `nop()` and specify them by name, rather use `lambda` as you showed, either one is fine.  Another example that pretty much comes down to personal taste.

Comment: Interesting. My professor specifically stated to make another function, but I guess I will just do it another way. Thanks.

Comment: @kk.lau, `lambda` _does_ make another function, it's just not defined the same way. i.e. `f = lambda x: x` defines exactly the same function  as `def f(x): return x`. (you can't use the later as a default argument, though)

Comment: Yes, I knew this, but for some reason it wasn't processing. Maybe it was the 9 hours of straight homework I've been doing. Thank you :)